# 2 different loops - both don't work

Tags: javascript

I'm working on my own simple snake version :)

So there is a single canvas with a rectangle on it. When I hit 'up' the rectangle should move upwards, when I hit 'down' it should go downwards and so on.

But I don't want to have to always stay on the specific button. I want a loop to start whenever a key is pressed. And the loop should stop whenever another key is pressed - which will then start a new loop.

Till now I tried two different versions: one with a while loop and one with a setTimeout() function. Both don't work as I want them to. While() just puts the rectangle to the start of the y-axis and setTimeout() doesn't seem to call itself again. Where's my mistake?

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("can");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var x_coor = 230;
    var y_coor = 230;
    ctx.fillStyle = "darkgrey";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.height, canvas.width);
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillRect(x_coor, y_coor, 20, 20);

    var move = {
      x_koor: 230,
      y_koor: 230,
      whichKey: function(event) {
        var taste = event.keyCode;
        if (taste == 38) { // up
          this.up();
        } else if (taste == 40) { // down
          this.down();
        } else if (taste == 37) { // left
          x_koor = this.left();
        } else if (taste == 39) { // right
          x_koor = this.right();
        }
      },
      up: function() {
        while (this.y_koor > 0) {
          this.y_koor -= 1;
          ctx.fillStyle = "darkgrey";
          ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.height, canvas.width);
          ctx.fillStyle = "black";
          ctx.fillRect(this.x_koor, this.y_koor, 20, 20);
        }
      },
      down: function() {
        if (y_coor < canvas.height - 20) {
          y_coor += 1;
          x_coor = x_coor;
          ctx.fillStyle = "darkgrey";
          ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.height, canvas.width);
          ctx.fillStyle = "black";
          ctx.fillRect(x_coor, y_coor, 20, 20);
          window.setTimeout(this.down, 10);
        }
      },
      // and so on...
      window.addEventListener("keydown", move.whichKey.bind(move));
    }
```

```html
<canvas id="can" height="500" width="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: Event handlers don't run until Javascript returns to the main event loop. So while the `while` loop is running, `y_koor` will never change.

Comment: Have you considered running a single loop and changing the `offset` based on the key pressed?

Comment: @Barmar So how should I manage it instead?

Comment: You should use `setInterval` or `setTimeout` to do something repeatedly without blocking the UI.

Comment: @Barmar that's what I did in the 'down' function. But it still doesn't repeat itself without having to stay on the downkey.

Comment: I think it should be `setTimeout(this.down.bind(this), 10)`

Comment: @Barmar Ok, it works - thanks! Now there's still no possibility to interrupt the loop, when another key is pressed. When I hit the downkey two times consecutively, the speed doubles. Also when I 'hit' down and then 'left', the rectangle is going sidewards and downwards. It should be either left or right.

Comment: Instead of separate functions for up and down, use a single function for all directions. It can check a variable that says which way it should go, and this would be set by the keyboard handler.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, I find it easiest to have a single main game loop. Here, I'm simply keeping track of the last direction set, and handling it in the main game loop (in this case, the setInterval).

I hope this helps, and is what you were looking for.

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("can");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var x_coor = 58;
    var y_coor = 58;
    var size = 4;
    var dirX = 0;
    var dirY = 0;
    ctx.fillStyle = "darkgrey";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.height, canvas.width);
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillRect(x_coor, y_coor, size, size);
    
    window.addEventListener("keydown", keyDown);
    
    function keyDown(e) {
        switch (e.keyCode) {
            case 38:
                dirX = 0;
                dirY = -1;
                break;
            case 40:
                dirX = 0;
                dirY = 1;
                break;
            case 37:
                dirX = -1;
                dirY = 0;
                break;
            case 39:
                dirX = 1;
                dirY = 0;
                break;
        }
    }
    
    setInterval(function() {
        x_coor += dirX * size;
        y_coor += dirY * size;
        coordLoop();
        ctx.fillStyle = "darkgrey";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.height, canvas.width);
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.fillRect(x_coor, y_coor, size, size);
    }, 200);
    
    function coordLoop() {
        if (x_coor > canvas.width) {
            x_coor = 0;
        }
        if (x_coor < 0) {
            x_coor = canvas.width - size;
        }
        if (y_coor > canvas.height) {
            y_coor = 0;
        }
        if (y_coor < 0) {
            y_coor = canvas.height - size;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="can" height="120" width="120"></canvas>
```